# Unable to get updated value from the INI file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am using ConfigParser and reading all values in the code and which is working well, Also able to save field value at runtime in the INI. Running this code every 60 seconds.

Issue is when I read field value on next run (i.e. after 60 seconds) getting initial value and not the updated one. I can see between run that INI file is correctly updated but still it's reading earlier value i.e. before dynamic update.

```
    Config.read("vSSF_MCC_GR.INI")
    print('Config Sections Are during execution:-',Config.sections())
    FLAG1 = ConfigSectionMap("vSSFConfiguration")['mode']
    print("FLAG VALUE IS during execution %s",FLAG1)
    failed_gw = ConfigSectionMap("vSSFConfiguration")['failed_gw']
    FLAG1 <<modified here>> using Config.set but above print for FLAG1 still displaying OLD value not the one updated by above Config.set done
```

I am using Config.set to modify field value in the INI file.Here A

Comment: It may help if you post a sample of  `vSSF_MCC_GR.INI`.

Comment: [vSSFConfiguration]
mode = FORCE_NORMAL

Comment: Looks like I m reading INI file using  "Config1 = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        Config1.read("vSSF_MCC_GR.INI")" but not closing this after modifications and not able to find how to close Config1 because there is no method like Config1.Close() and this causes each time read is returning old value not the updated ones

Comment: Config1 = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        Config1.read("vSSF_MCC_GR.INI")
        print('Config Sections Are during execution:-',Config1.sections())
        FLAG1 = ConfigSectionMap("vSSFConfiguration")['mode']
        print("FLAG VALUE IS during execution %s",FLAG1) <<THIS PRINTS Values Present in the INI FILE>>